# Sql Script Get Character Location

Tags: mysql, sql

Best way to get first and last specific character in SQL column using SQL script.

For example my column contains value "a/b/c/" and I would like to get first '/' character then last one.

So I will get values where '/' first appeared in 1st character and last one in 5th character.

Comment: So from the given example `a/b/c/` it should not return anything since first `/` appears in 2nd and last in 6th char respectively.

Comment: *start from zero position..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if the character `/` is on a certain part of a given string using `substring` function. Note that you are counting 0 as the first position where in the function the first position is 1. So using below you can get the string on a desired position

```
mysql> select substring('a/b/c/',2,1);
+-------------------------+
| substring('a/b/c/',2,1) |
+-------------------------+
| /                       |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select substring('a/b/c/',6,1);
+-------------------------+
| substring('a/b/c/',6,1) |
+-------------------------+
| /                       |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you are writing a query to select if the above condition is true then it could be as

```
select * from table_name
where
substring(col_name,2,1) = '/' 
and
substring(col_name,6,1) = '/'
```

Note that 0 is first position as per you but for the function its 1, so added +1 to get the position.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the index of the your characters first and last occurrence you can try something like this,

```
     SELECT LENGTH("a/b/c/") - LOCATE('/', REVERSE("a/b/c/")) + 1 AS LastIndex ,instr('a/b/c/', '/') AS FirstIndex;
```